# Memory Leak & Slowdown with SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: macos, performance, memory-leaks, swiftui

I'm experiencing a dramatic increase in Memory footprint and slowdown of my macOS SwiftUI app. I was able to create a minimal example to reproduce. To reproduce go Xcode -> File -> New -> Project -> macOS -> App -> Life Cycle: SwiftUI App and paste&replace this into `*App.swift`

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var number = 0.0
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            List {}
            .toolbar(content: {
                ForEach(1..<100) { _ in
                    Text(String(format: "Time elapsed: %.1f ", number))
                        .font(.system(.body, design: .monospaced))
                }
            })
            .onReceive(timer) { input in
                number += 0.1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I profiled the app and it has as massive number of leaks and memory footprint grows quickly:
[image: XCode Profiler]

This bug is preventing me from launching my app. What can I do?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I might add to your question, since it wasn't immediately clear until I started to try to debug it, that this seems like it's directly related to `toolbar`

Comment: @jnpdx yes, in this example it's only the toolbar. But in my actual app I still got similar leaking behaviour after taking out the toolbar, even though it was much reduced. But I wasn't able to track it down where it came from. There seems to be something fundamentally going wrong.

Comment: I filed a TSI (Technical Support Incident) with Apple. Let's see what they reply

Comment: @JohnHenryk Did you ever get a reply? looks like https://github.com/matt-curtis/mac-swiftui-toolbar-memory-leak-demo to me

Comment: @mattsven No, never had a reply. But I've noticed the issue seems to be resolved in macOS 12 beta.

Comment: @mattsven No, never had a reply. But I've noticed the issue seems to be resolved in macOS 12 beta.